# How do I create an executable with a MySQL database inside it?

Tags: java, sql, database, eclipse

I wanted to create an executable of my java application in eclipse, but instead of having to hosting my database, I wanted to putting inside the application's folders when creating the executable, what do I need to do to accomplish this, and also, what would the path of the class with the code to connect to the database be like?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can have a look SQLite or similar solutions. However the question as it stands is too broad and searches for libraries etc. are considered off topic too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with MySQL, since MySQL runs in "server mode" only.

To do what you want you would need to change the database to one of the following:

- **H2**. See [documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html). URL: `jdbc:h2:file:<path>/<database>`
- **HyperSQL**. See [documentation](http://hsqldb.org/). URL: `jdbc:hsqldb:file:<path>/<database>`
- **Apache Derby**. See [documentation](https://db.apache.org/derby/). URL: `jdbc:derby:<path>/<database>`

In all three databases the corresponding JDBC driver includes the WHOLE database engine itself. Therefore, just by connecting to the database, you'll get a fully running instance of it.

Now, these databases can work on several modes:

- **Embedded+File System**: the JDBC URL will include a [relative or absolute] path to a directory where the database tables and data are persisted.
- **Embedded+Memory**: the JDBC URL will specify all data will be stored in memory and will be lost once the connection is closed.
- **Server Mode**: the JDBC URL will point to an [external/remote] *host:port* where the database engine is running. This is similar to MySQL.

According to your question, the first option seems to be the one you need. As a personal note, I find H2 and HyperSQL are easier to set up compared to Derby, since each one comes into a single JAR file.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look into the options you gave me, h2 seems to be easy to set up.

Answer (score -1):

A database is either located on a user's local machine (for development), or on a server on the internet (for real world use). You could create a Java class that imitates a database, but it's impossible to put a database inside an executable.

Comment: Ohhh, is there a way to host a database for free?

Comment: Yep, look into setting up MySQL, MongoDB, or any other type of database on your local computer

Comment: It's perfectly possible. As far as I know, there are at least three databases that do that: H2, HyperSQL, and Apache Derby.